# Is it still common to hear the expression 'go bonkers' in the US in daily conversations?

Tags: phrase-usage, vocabulary

I did some looking into and found out that the expression 'go bonkers' was more prevalent throughout the '90s in the US. I've read somewhere that it's use has started to wane at around 2004, and not very common nowadays. However, just a week or so ago, I've heard someone use the expression for the first time in--I must say-almost 20 years. Do people in the US still use this expression often? Or is it more common to hear people say 'go crazy' or 'go nuts'?

Comment: I haven't heard it in years, but I imagine there are pockets, or areas where expressions are still in use, re-used or even unique...

Comment: Compared to a couple of other common expressions (go nuts, go crazy), [go bonkers](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go+bonkers%2Cgo+nuts%2Cgo+crazy&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20bonkers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20nuts%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20crazy%3B%2Cc0) is hardly used, though at the year 2000 it was still on an upward trajectory.

Comment: Wow, even I know this. Although I am a non-native I heard this in TV series and saw it in books.

Comment: Thanks for your answers everyone! Definitely helped me to get a better sense of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

2004 was definitely [the banner year](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bonkers&year_start=1800&year_end=2017&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbonkers%3B%2Cc0) for *bonkers*, but use has only dipped slightly since then.  I can't say I hear it every day, but it isn't exactly *beswevened*.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. One question: What does 'beswevened' mean?

Comment: @Archi-TechLee -- a _sweven_ was a vision or a hallucination.  Someone _beswevened_ would be delusional.  The word is much, much less common than "bonkers"; I don't know for a fact it has ever been used.

Comment: I see. So it was sort of a creation of your own to befuddle me.... Cute. Thanks.

Comment: @Archi-TechLee -- to make you bonkers!  No, I was just looking for a truly archaic word for _insane_ and this was the best I could do.

Comment: OK. Got it! I've looked up the word _sweven_. Thanks for clearing that up for me. I don't exactly know why, but somehow you remind me of the character Peter Van Houten in 'The Fault In Our Stars' by John Green.